# How to find in Eclipse which classes implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

Using Eclipse, how can I find which Java classes implement interface A *AND* interface B? Thanks.

Comment: Produce a Javadoc from your code.  Look up interface A.  Look up interface B.  Write down the common implementation classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and I'm really missing this feature in the Eclipse search dialog. Going through all classes manually wasn't very pleasant, so I used this **nasty workaround**. Given this structure:

```
public interface A {
  public String x();
}
public interface B {
}

public class ImplementsBoth implements A, B {

  @Override
  public String x() {...}

}
public class ImplementsA implements A {

  @Override
  public String x() {...}

}
public class ImplementsB implements B {

}
```

I changed B into:

```
public interface B {
  public void x();
}
```

This results in the following error for `ImplementsBoth`:

> The return type is incompatible with B.x()

Now it's possible to step through all these messages in the Problems view.

Comment: This basically identifies all classes which implements B somewhere in their hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+H, in file search tab search for "[implements A,B | implements B,A]" while file type is *.java.

Comment: That only works some of the time.  It won't work, for example, with a class that "implements A, C, B" and it also won't find interfaces with a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Search -> File... -> `public * implements *,*` or another pattern.

Comment: Neither this nor http://stackoverflow.com/a/10075531/348975 will return D when `interface A { } interface B { } interface C extends A , B { } interface D extends C { }`.  I don't know a solution that will.